# c++ video capture using opencv

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, video-capture

I try to capture video using Logitech C920 webcam with full hd resolution. It provides 30 fps with this resolution.

It works with windows camera application at 30 fps but whatever I try, I could not get this fps rate with opencv videoCapture.

Note: I use windows 10 and vs15. 
I tried with different usb ports, opencv versions and codecs. Result is same, ~5 fps.

I measured fps ignoring first 10 frames. Here are my calculations: only read = "5.04fps" , read+imshow = "4.97fps" and read+imshow+write = "4.91fps"

```
void main()
{
    mainStream.open(0);
    mainStream.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
    mainStream.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);
    mainStream.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 30);
    mainStream.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));
    mainWriter.open("outputnew2.avi", CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 30, cv::Size(frameW, frameH), true);
    namedWindow("frame", 1);

    while (true){
        Mat frame;
        mainStream >> frame;
        imshow("frame", frame);
        if (waitKey(5) == 27)
            break;
        mainWriter << frame;
    }
    mainStream.release();
    mainWriter.release();
}
```

Comment: What are the symptoms that make you think that you do not obtain the appropriate fps? Can you show all the code along with `VideoCapture` constructor?

Comment: maybe its because of capturing frames in main thread . but when i try with other full hd cameras this setup works fine

Comment: Yeah, "maybe". Anyway, without the code and actual/desired output no one will be able to help.

Comment: ok, i have edited the code

Comment: OK, and what precisely is wrong with your program? No matter how slow your PC might be, the output video `outputnew2.avi` for sure has 1920x1080 resolution with 30fps. Also, better don't use `operator>>`, use `read` instead, because it returns `bool` and you can check if there is a new frame. Also `imshow` is rather slow ...

Comment: I used read instead of operator >> and nothing changed

Comment: Not always this set property works as intended, and sometimes not at all... it could be that 30fps is not supported (maybe it is 29 or 25).Try not setting all of them, and calculate the speed, and then only the size ones and do it again. Try setting different fps as well.

Comment: Logitech only claim the camera can be read at 30fps, whereas you are trying to read the camera, display the image, compress the image and write it to disk at 30fps - which is different. Try removing all the displaying and writing - you may need to do it in a different thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

The `imshow` method is very slow (in a pretty relative scope). Try to measure the real fps while you do *not* show the image and do *not* write the image to a file.

After that is done, you can check the real fps and determine which one of the two options (showing or writing) is slowing down your achieved fps rate.

Please post results of the achieved fps rate without showing or writing the image.

Edit:

Alright, you nearly always get 5 fps, which is kind of slow. Does the saved video (or images) match the resolution you wanted? Are they really 1920x1080
?

In that case, do the measured times differ from release and debug build?

Edit2:

If the same code works with other usb cams (and they produce more fps than the C920) my immediate suspect is the C920 itself (or its driver at least). Does it help if you deinstall the driver for it (eventually reboot) and install the newest driver again?

Another thing: Do the measured fps change if you do not request 30 but maybe like 20 fps?

Edit3:

It seems it was a driver issue (merged from comments). Reinstalling the driver is one method to adress this

Comment: ok i measured fps ignoring first 10 frames. Here are my calculations: only read = "5.04fps" , read+imshow = "4.97fps" and read+imshow+write = "4.91fps"

Comment: @M.E. I updated the answer. You may also update your measured results from the comment into your question, as it helps in solving your issue.

Comment: Thanks @MauriceRandomNumber. Yes, output frames are in 1920x1080 resolution and i measured times for release mode. Logitech c920 and other fhd cam are usb cams.

Comment: Now this is odd. Did you try different USB ports as well? Updated the answer to ask for a reinstall of driver software ;-)

Comment: ok. i reinstall the camera driver and its ok now. opencv is innocent! Many thanks @MauriceRandomNumber.